# phonegap social sharing button issue android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to create an app with phonegap and I want to include a sharing button. I couldn't make it so I created a new empty project from phonegap. I just have the sample page displayed and nothing else, when I try it on my phone. Now i want to simply add a basic sharing button.
Following the instructions here : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
I went to my project folder and just installed the plugin with the phonegap command.
Then in my index.html I simply added this :

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Message only')">message only</button>
```

But when I click it, nothing happens.
I also tried the other given buttons and solutions but none works. Any ideas? I'm struggling with this for 2 days!

Thank you in advance for your answers :)

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem, but you code works fine on my device. So make sure you installed the plugin properly. Check if your project contains a plugins folder with a subfolder called cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing. In doubt reinstall the plugin.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55gzEfTz4dY
I don't understand what's wrong ?

Comment: Note that if your adding the plugin via the command line you don't have to perform the steps described in the "Manually" section.

Comment: Yes, but even when i just add the plugin via command line, it doesn't work...

Comment: Then you'll have to debug your app in detail. Connecting your phone to your pc and taking a look at your app with [chrome inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Should the button work on the unbuilded app ? I mean with the preview app PhoneGap on the phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this setup.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#manually
 Add the following xml to all the config.xml files you can find

**For IOS:**

```
<feature name="SocialSharing"><param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" /></feature>
```

**For Android**

```
<feature name="SocialSharing"><param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" /></feature>
```

**For Windows Phone**

```
<feature name="SocialSharing"><param name="wp-package" value="SocialSharing"/></feature>
```

For sharing remote images (or other files) on Android, the file needs to be stored locally first, so add this permission to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For iOS, you'll need to add the Social.framework and MessageUI.framework to your project. 
Click your project, Build Phases, Link Binary With Libraries, search for and add Social.framework and MessageUI.framework.2. 
Grab a copy of SocialSharing.js, add it to your project and reference it in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
```

Download the source files for iOS and/or Android and copy them to your project.iOS: Copy SocialSharing.h and SocialSharing.m to platforms/ios//Plugins
Android: Copy SocialSharing.java to platforms/android/src/nl/xservices/plugins (create the folders)Window Phone: Copy SocialSharing.cs to platforms/wp8/Plugins/nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing (create the folders)

Comment: Of course i followed this setup, i tried to do it with an empty project first but stil doesn't work. I create a new project with phonegap, then i use the command to install the plugin, and i follow everything. In my index.html in www i just include the button but it does nothing when i press it... :(